# Регулярное выражение для поиск товаров и их кол-во в тексте

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Никак не могу придумать регулярку для поиск товаров в тексте.

Например:

```
 Нам нужно купить завтра к вечеру
 1. бананы 10 шт
 2. картошка 20 кг
 3. капуста 1кг
 ах да, а еще нужна 
 вода миниральная 5 л
```

В тексте товар всегда начинается с новой строки, и я могу каждую строку проверить на то - это товарная позиция или нет, но перед товаром может быть какое-то значение (чаще всего номер), а может и не быть.
Оптимально высчитывать по еденице измерения.
Вот только не пойму как сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Под все случаи невозможно подстроится, но конкретно для вашего примера подойдёт следующее регулярное выражение:

```
/^(?:[^a-zа-яё]*)(?<good>[a-zа-яё ]+?\d+\s?(шт|кг|л))$/gim
```

Пример на JS:

```js
let rExp = /^(?:[^a-zа-яё]*)(?<good>[a-zа-яё ]+?\d+\s?(шт|кг|л))$/gim;
let sTxt = `Нам нужно купить завтра к вечеру
 1. бананы 10 шт
 2. картошка 20 кг
 3. капуста 1кг
 ах да, а еще нужна 
 вода миниральная 5 л`;
 
console.log( [...sTxt.matchAll(rExp)].map(el => el.groups.good) );
```

Comment: Да у меня своих вариантов тоже много. Просто мне хочет посмотреть другими глазами на это и мб что-то общее сделаю + буду пропускать через несколько регулярок. 
Спс за ваш вариант.